# What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, nosql

What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?

(This is a reposting of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net) on Stack Overflow, which was closed long ago.)

I'd appreciate any up-to-date recommendations, especially for minimal solutions with maybe only a few thousand records.

Also, is it a good idea to store objects in serialized form, for example using JSON, or does this cause too many backwards-compatibility problems later when the program is updated and the objects have been changed somewhat?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't gotten any answers (or even any views of my question), so here's my very non-authoritative answer, based on some googling and some testing of one of the programs.

There's a comprehensive list of NoSQL databases here: http://nosql-database.org/

So you can search that web page for ".net" or "c#", and get a complete (and quite large) list of possibilities. And don't forget to click on "A NoSQL parody" over in the right hand column.

For large systems two leading contenders are these:

mongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/  https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

RavenDB: https://ravendb.net/

For medium-sized systems this one seems to be popular:

DBreeze: https://github.com/hhblaze/DBreeze

For small, perhaps serverless, systems there's these two:

LiteDB: http://www.litedb.org/

RaptorDB: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375413/RaptorDB-the-Document-Store

All of the above are written in C# except for mongoDB, which has a "C# driver".

After a bit of testing I've chosen LiteDB for my program. It seems to be well-maintained and has quite a bit of usage - it's been forked almost 500 times on GitHub.

(I also asked if it was a good idea to store serialized .Net objects in a database. I'm still very interested in possible answers / opinions on that question.)

Comment: https://martendb.io/

Comment: [linqdb](http://linqdb.net/)